# In c programming when calling by reference, float value take zero value

Tags: c, floating-point

When I enter float value for r in circle, It always take zero value.
area and perimeter of circle result is zero because r take zero value.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
void circle(float, float *, float *);
main()
{
    float radius, area, perimeter;
    printf("Enter radius:");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    circle(radius, &area, &perimeter);
    printf("radius:%f area: %f, perimeter:%f ", radius, area, perimeter);
}
void circle(r, ar, per)
float r, *ar, *per;
{
    *ar =3.14*(r*r);
    *per =2*3.14*r;
}
```

Comment: Please show sample input and output.

Comment: You're mixing ANSI prototyping with a K&R implementation. Don't do that.

Comment: There is no "calling by reference" in C programming.

Comment: If the prototype mismatch (referred to in other comments and answers) is indeed the problem here, it's yet another reminder to *use a good compiler, and enable warnings*.  Me, I wouldn't have spotted that particular error, but when I compiled your code, my compiler said "`warning: promoted type 'double' of K&R function parameter is not compatible with the parameter type 'float' declared in a previous prototype`".

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: There is calling by reference in C. Per established use, “passing by reference” means passing a pointer to a thing. People working with C++ invented a new thing, a built-in type in the language, and adopted the term “reference” for it. But that new use of terminology only applies to C++. It does not change the existing use of the terminology in C or other languages. Per the C standard (C 2018 6.2.5 20), a pointer “provides a reference to an entity,” so passing a pointer passes a reference, and that is what people talking mean when talking about references in C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's my understanding of "passing by reference": When a called function assigns a value to its parameter then the same value will be assigned to the corresponding argument (in the calling function). And, I'm sure this usage isn't new. Fortran, for example, was (is?) such a language. In that sense, there is no pass by reference in C.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: No, assigning the same **value** to a parameter is passing by value. FORTRAN used built-in pass by reference, where a parameter designated the same **object** as an argument (although “object” may not have been the term originally used for it). In C, pass by reference is performed manually, instead of built-in, by passing a reference (a pointer). If the argument `&x` is passed for a parameter `int *p`, then `&x` is passed by value to `p`, and, simultaneously, `x` is passed by reference; `*p` refers to `x`. This terminology was used before C++ was around.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think you misunderstood. I meant, assignment to parameter takes place in the called function: `void f(int p) { p = 42; }`, `void g(void) { int a = 53; f(a); if (a == 42) puts("Passing by reference"); }`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: The terminology use is as I have described it. “Pass by reference” is not used just to mean passing addresses built into a programming language; it is also used to mean passing addresses manually.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not convinced. That terminology is used neither in the Standard nor in the K&R2.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: Neither the C standard nor K&R are documents about the use of language in programming. Nobody said “pass by reference” is an official term. It is simply common usage. Searching Stack Overflow for “[C] pass by reference” will turn up plenty of results where people use the term thusly. Nor do you have grounds to correct people who do so; if you want to rely on authoritative documents, you have none that say people may not use the term this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have incorrect function definition. This code will work:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

void circle(float, float *, float *);

int main()
{
    float radius, area, perimeter;
    printf("Enter radius:");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    circle(radius, &area, &perimeter);
    printf("radius:%f area: %f, perimeter:%f ", radius, area, perimeter);
    return 0;
}

void circle(float r, float *ar, float *per)
{
    *ar =3.14*(r*r);
    *per =2*3.14*r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that you entered an incorrect sequence of symbols for a float number.

Write for example

```
if ( scanf("%f",&radius) == 1 )
{
    circle(radius, &area, &perimeter);
    printf("radius:%f area: %f, perimeter:%f ", radius, area, perimeter);
}
else
{
    puts( "Error: incorrect input." );
}
```

But in any case the function declaration

```
void circle(float, float *, float *);
```

does not correspond to the function definition

```
void circle(r, ar, per)
float r, *ar, *per;
{
    *ar =3.14*(r*r);
    *per =2*3.14*r;
}
```

Declare the function in the function definition like

```
void circle(float r, float *ar, float *per )
{
    *ar =3.14*(r*r);
    *per =2*3.14*r;
}
```

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)

6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)

> 3 An identifier list in a function declarator that is not part of a
> definition of that function shall be empty.

So you may not mix a function prototype with a function with an identifier list.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```